# PostgreSQL database size is not reasonable

Tags: postgresql, performance, tuples, postgresql-performance

In my postgresql 9.6 instance I have 1 production database. When I query the size of all databases :

```
combit=> Select pg_database.datname,pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size(pg_database.datname)) as size from pg_database;
  datname  |  size   
-----------+---------
 template0 | 7265 kB
 combit    | 285 GB
 postgres  | 7959 kB
 template1 | 7983 kB
 repmgr    | 8135 kB
(5 rows)
```

When I check what are the big tables in my database (includes indexes) :

```
combit=> SELECT nspname || '.' || relname AS "relation",
combit->     pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size(C.oid)) AS "total_size"
combit->   FROM pg_class C
combit->   LEFT JOIN pg_namespace N ON (N.oid = C.relnamespace)
combit->   WHERE nspname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema')
combit->     AND C.relkind <> 'i'
combit->     AND nspname !~ '^pg_toast'
combit->   ORDER BY pg_total_relation_size(C.oid) DESC
combit->   LIMIT 20;
      relation           | total_size 
-----------------------------+------------
 rep.ps_rf_inst_prod      | 48 GB
 rep.nap_inter_x5         | 46 GB
 rep.man_x5               | 16 GB
 rep.tc_fint_x5           | 9695 MB
 rep.nap_ip_debit_x5      | 7645 MB
 rep.ip__billing      | 5458 MB
 rep.ps_rd            | 3417 MB
 rep.nap_ip_discount      | 3147 MB
 rep.custo_x5             | 2154 MB
 rep.ip_service_discou_x5 | 1836 MB
 rep.tc_sub_rate__x5      | 294 MB
```

The total sum is not more than 120G.

When I check the fs directly :

```
[/data/base] : du -sk * | sort -n
7284    13322
7868    13323
7892    1
8156    166694
298713364       16400
```

[/data/base] :

16400 is the oid of the combit database. As you can see the size of combit on the fs is about 298G.

I checked for dead tuples in the biggest tables :

```
combit=>select relname,n_dead_tup,last_autoanalyze,last_analyze,last_autovacuum,last_vacuum from pg_stat_user_tables order by n_live_tup desc limit4;

  -[ RECORD 1 ]----+------------------------------
  relname          | ps_rf_inst_prod
  n_dead_tup       | 0
  last_autoanalyze | 2017-12-04 09:00:16.585295+02
  last_analyze     | 2017-12-05 16:08:31.218621+02
  last_autovacuum  | 
  last_vacuum      | 
  -[ RECORD 2 ]----+------------------------------
  relname          | man_x5
  n_dead_tup       | 0
  last_autoanalyze | 2017-12-05 06:02:07.189184+02
  last_analyze     | 2017-12-05 16:12:58.130519+02
  last_autovacuum  | 
  last_vacuum      | 
  -[ RECORD 3 ]----+------------------------------
  relname          | tc_fint_x5
  n_dead_tup       | 0
  last_autoanalyze | 2017-12-05 06:04:06.698422+02
  last_analyze     | 
  last_autovacuum  | 
  last_vacuum      | 
  -[ RECORD 4 ]----+------------------------------
  relname          | nap_inter_x5
  n_dead_tup       | 0
  last_autoanalyze | 2017-12-04 08:54:16.764392+02
  last_analyze     | 2017-12-05 16:10:23.411266+02
  last_autovacuum  | 
  last_vacuum      |
```

I run vacuum full on all 5 top tables 2 hours ago and it didnt free alot of space...

On this database the only operations that happen are truncate , insert and select. So how can it be that I had dead tuples on some of my tables ? If I only run truncate,select,insert query tuples shouldnt be created..

And the bigger question, Where are the missing 180G ?

Comment: You've excluded TOAST and index space there, have you?

Comment: The pg_total_size includes indexes and toasts

Comment: If `pg_total_relation_size()` isn't adding up, you could try approaching this from the other end, i.e. try to tie each file in `data/base/16400/` back to a table and see if anything's unaccounted for. `SELECT oid::regclass, pg_relation_filepath(oid) FROM pg_class` will help (though this only reports the first segment of the main fork, so for `/base/16400/123`, you'd also need to count `123.1`, `123.2`, `123_fsm`, etc.). The storage layout is documented [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/storage-file-layout.html).

Comment: The files in the directory /base/16400/xxx suppose to be the relfilenode of the table right ? When I run 'select relname,relfilenode,oid from pg_class where relfilenode='xxx' I suppose to find the object that the file represnts right ? The problem is that the result of this query are empty...

Comment: Any idea ? someone ?

Comment: `relfilenode='xxx'` will miss a few things; `pg_relation_filenode(oid)='xxx'` is more comprehensive. There could also be uncommitted changes in `pg_class` which are not visible to you, so strictly speaking I think you'd need to be in [single-user mode](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-postgres.html#APP-POSTGRES-SINGLE-USER) with no [prepared transactions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-prepare-transaction.html) to get any guarantees. Even then, I'm not going to claim that it's 100% safe to delete anything...

Comment: If everything points to some of these files being orphaned, it might be worth asking on [pgsql-general](https://www.postgresql.org/list/) whether there's anything else to check; not sure what else to suggest, other than taking a binary copy of the server and testing the hell out  of it. Of course, you can easily reclaim the space by recreating the database from a `pg_dump`, if you can afford the downtime...

Comment: Yeah, I sent them a mail. Waiting for response. I can afford the downtime but I want to understand the reason behind this weird scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wanted to mention that the solution was dumping the database with pg_dump into a file, dropping the database and then restoring it. I had in the database`s directory files that represented objects that were no longer exist.